# Ways to improve reputation that aren't asking or answering?

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I would like to have two more reputation points (I have 48 reputation points now) so I can comment on other people's posts here as I need [50 reputation points in order to comment everywhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

But, I don't have another question to ask and I don't want to answer again until I've thought about the site some more.

Is there any other way to get more reputation?

Comment: Suggest an edit that improves a post. If two high-rep users review the edit and agree it's an improvement, you will earn 2 rep points. You can do this again and again, though at some point the rep earned from suggesting good edits does cap out. Also, at this point, it would repay your time to read the help files (in this case, [help/what's-rep](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)), and the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/273503).

Comment: Or you could look through the faq that tells you how to get rep.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (and Mitch), I linked to that very page, plus the "Overall StackExchange FAQ", in the very first comment on this question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am sorry other people do not like my question. I liked it. Is the answer a secret?

Comment: Yeah, I can't VtD yet either. Sigh. Maybe it's worth putting in the effort for one last push over 20K. I just am tired of rep.

Comment: @Rathony Do not give OP anything he doesn't earn. Sets a bad precedent. Also, I wouldn't mind a little bit of a delay of the ultimately inevitable time he can "contribute" to the commentary on arbitrary posts.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How long do comments take to be approved?

Comment: I tried with this post: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250325/is-there-a-germanic-word-for-the-latin-number

Comment: @BuddhaTheis That was a solid first attempt. The only problem was "adding content not in the original". Even if the content is helpful, that practice is frowned upon, because it puts words in OP's mouth that we're not sure he would want there. The only time we suggest chaning content, rather than merely formatting, in a post, is adding references/citations/sources. Otherwise, your edit was good.

Comment: @DanBron the person who posted might not have wanted a footnote there. I understand. I will do better in the future.

Comment: @BuddhaTheis Yep, you got it. The way for *you* to add footnotes to *others'* posts, is via the comments, which will automatically attribute them to you, rather than OP. That's honestly what they're for. Though I'm not sure how useful or valueable such footnotes are for simply defining words OP has used. Anyone who is confused upon encountering a word they're unfamiliar with can use the standard tools (i.e. a dictionary) to resolve that for themselves. We also expect the large part of the population of this site to be familiar with such terms as "cognate", anyway.

Comment: @DanBron I will try another one to see if I can get things right now.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I deleted the thank you from this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301231/should-the-word-worthwhile-be-followed-by-a-to-infinitive-or-gerund

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have the reputation now. I didn't like removing someone else's thank you. It seemed mean.

Comment: I approved both edits. Well, I technically hit "improve edit" on the first one, to remove the editorial footnote, but that still marks the edit as "approved". I just straight-up hit the approve button on the "removed thanks" edit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Should I do anything else on this one? It has no capital letter at the start or question mark at the end.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok. Do you know why I have to delete the thank yous?

Comment: @BuddhaTheis [This is why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/273503). You really should start getting familiar with the FAQs and other material in the help center and meta.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok. No problem. Not everyone always agrees on things. I'm going to take a break now and come back later.

Comment: @DanBron I'll look over it later. Thanks Dan.

Comment: This list of comments should be deleted. They exist to help the OP, but he decided to delete his account. The comments are of no use to anyone else.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Now that we know Budda was a sock puppet of a known troll (well, not technically a troll so much as an attention-seeking user), I'd say the question itself likely wasn't asked in good faith, and the whole enchilada should be deleted. But I can't vote-to-delete.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There was a whole thread on Meta.SE where Budda asked why his account was deleted. Turns out it was a sock puppet of another account. He has two socks, actually. Anyway, not the mods but he himself outed himself as Peter David-Carter, who previously earned himself a long suspension for similar, and similarly-annoying, behavior. Is he back? Where?

Comment: @DanBron can't vote to delete, there's an upvoted answer. I reversed my upvote, downvoted but nada. If Rathony deletes his post, then the question is deletable. Ah, Peter David-Carter. Yes. Same sort of writing style.

Comment: Responding to comments is a lot of fun, but it is adding nothing to this question, which adds nothing to the site. Search  and reading the FAQ are there to avoid having questions like this. Please vote to close so we can then delete, whether the OP was a troll or not.

Comment: @Mitch I voted to close this question. I don't think this question should be deleted as it could be reference for other new users in the future. I think comments will be taken care of by moderators.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't delete an accepted answer.

Comment: @Rathony Flag it and ask the mods to do it for you, if you want the Q (and your answer) deleted. But being a duplicate Q prevents it from deleted too. So just leave it, eventually the whole post will sink to oblivion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think you understood my comment. You said to DanBron that "if Rathony deletes his post, then..." No, I can't delete. I told Mitch "I don't think this question should be deleted".

Comment: I thought you had a change of heart. Showing chinks in your armour, so to speak. Evidently, no fear of that happening anytime soon. The comment to Dan Brown was june 11th, time to move on!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I wonder how you can be so unfamiliar with how it works here. Sometimes it surprises me.

Comment: I explained, let me repeat it a second time. I thought you had changed your mind. Is that clearer, now? You seriously think this post and this train of comments will interest anybody in five months from now? You surprise me sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 5 reputation points from an upvote of your question and 10 points from that of your answer.

You lose 2 reputation points when your questions or answers are downvoted. The best way seems to be either edit another (not your own) post to get two points or flag the following question for moderator's attention and ask a moderator to delete your question.

One of your questions has 9 downvotes. You will recover 18 reputation points when this question is deleted.

For further information, please read [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

As @DanBron commented, if you post a question or answer that could attract so many downvotes again, the system might block you from posting anything. You had better be careful when you ask and answer.

[Help Center > Privileges > Edit Questions And Answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Ah, interesting suggestion. But do please remind the user that **deleting bad content makes it more difficult to get out of a ban**, should their future submissions continue to be downvoted. It is better to *edit the question* into something useful for the site, so that people can either nullify their downvotes, or in the best case, reverse their downvotes (i.e. upvote).

Comment: I like it, but I was more addressing the advice about deleting the original bad question, not so much in avoiding repeating that error (which you are correct, is more important).

Comment: +1 for suggesting that the user deletes his unsalvageable post. I fear if he did edit, it would only make matters worst.

Comment: Editing sounds like a good idea. How do I edit? I have edited lots of comments and my questions but I don't get any more reputation from that.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's at the same place on other people's posts?

Comment: @Rathony What would make it a bad edit?

Comment: If OP edits *his own* posts, he won't go through review.  @Buddha, don't worry about what's a *bad edit*, worry about what's a *good edit*. You can, as Rathony suggests, simply avoid the whole question by deleting that post and regaining a handful of rep. That's perfectly fine, *so long as your future contributions are worthwhile and not downvoted or closevoted*. If, however, you do want to rescue that terrible question, then *edit it so it's a good question*. Make it objective. Don't push a personal philosophy. Don't invent anything. Don't ask why people react negatively to errors.

Comment: @DanBron I think the answer to my -9 question is a secret people are not supposed to know about.

Comment: @Rathony Ok. I will make small edits. Should I edit new questions or the old ones? I noticed some of the old ones have more errors in them.

Comment: @BuddhaTheis That comment is the kind of baloney which will harm your reputation here, and is the first step on the primrose path to perdition. No one has a personal vendetta against you, there is no anti-you cabal, no secret conspiracy. Even thinking that way is egomaniacal. Just act .. normal.

Comment: @Rathony I had a little bit of a try at it.